# Is there a ROS node for ADVC-55 frame grabber?

Tags: ros, image, camera1394, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ROS node that supports ADVC-55? I tried camera1294 but it does not find the ADVC-55. coriander does not find it either. kino and dvgrab does work with the ADVC-55.

So is there anything available out there or do I have to implement my own node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50174/is-there-a-ros-node-for-advc-55-frame-grabber?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally got it to work with gscam (the pipe line I use is: dv1394src port=-1 ! video/x-dv ! dvdemux ! dvdec quality=5 drop-factor=1 ! ffmpegcolorspace). Unfortunately there is a delay that I cannot figure out were it is caused so we might go with an USB frame grabber instead since when we testes with an ordinary Web Cam we did not see this delay.

---

Originally posted by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) with karma: 1339 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0